# Swift (some) UITableViewDelegate Methods Not Executing

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, swift, ios8

I'm in the midst of transitioning some of my code from ObjC to Swift. So far so good, but I'm running into an issue with some of my UITableView's delegate methods not being called. In ObjC, I had my cells animate into the view using the `tableView willDisplayCell forRowAtIndexPath` method. While the method is suggested to me in Swift, it is never called. The same goes for `tableView willDisplayHeaderView forSection`, and `tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`.

I'm fairly sure my class is set properly:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

and my function declarations were suggested, so no way these are incorrect.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> [AnyObject]! {
    ...
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    ...
}

etc.
```

But while the tableView data shows up great, these individual delegate methods never seem to run. Is this a bug, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you tell to your table view about delegate and data source?

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I was initially getting errors when I tried that, but I think it was a bug. Adding those makes it work! Weird how the data was getting properly loaded despite the `self.tableView.dataSource  = self` line.

Comment: I should note that after adding these two lines, my app is acting REALLY strangely. i.e. some things that shouldn't be at all animated (UILabels and my UISegmentedControl) are...and it's generally super slow compared to before adding them. Wondering if something got mixed up in my Storyboard...

Comment: I did some tableView example. with label and picture and it's faster that in Objective-C, But I don't know how do you fill your tableview. Anyway, it's still beta, please consider.

Comment: Yeah, hoping it's a beta issue. Thanks for the answer, anyway!